# What is easiest way to custom display templates in SharePoint 2013 Search

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, display-template

I want to create custom display templates in SharePoint 2013 Search. I need the steps to create it. This is first time I am dealing with customization of search templates. Any step by step reference will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a custom display template, the best approach is to copy an existing one from Out-Of-Box display templates. With this, you can't overwrite the original one.

To reach the display templates

- From the Search Center navigate to Site Settings. In the Look and
  Feel section chose Design Manager.
- In Design Manager choose Upload Design Files.
- Click the link at the top of the page to open the Master Page Gallery
  in Windows Explorer.
- Browse down the folder structure to Display Templates/Search/

Read more about it on the following blogs as they used some example in it.
[Introduction to SharePoint 2013 Display Templates](http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/)

[SharePoint 2013 - Working with Display Template for Content Search Web Part](http://rwcchen.blogspot.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-working-with-display.html)

Comment: What if I have SP Foundation 2013?